# Norm of Triangle Matrix

Tags: analysis, matrices, functional-analysis, computer-science

How to find the norm of the following matrix, please? Thank you!

$$T := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},$$

and $$\|T\| = \sqrt{n^2+1}.$$

Comment: Which norm? There are several norms possible on the space of matrices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the matrix 2-norm:
$$
\|T\|=\sqrt{\lambda_\max(T^TT)}
$$